# Get the current number of the month of the financial year (Financial Year = from 1st of April to 31st of March)

Tags: sql

I am trying to get the number of current financial year in sql script
I would like to have the number 10 because February is the month 10 of the current financial year 2022/2023
Could you please help me?

Comment: Isn't February the 11th?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant. (You have already got a couple of product specific answer...)

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use Mod function to get what you need for the month. +8 will give you April as #1 (February as 11).  +7 will give you February as 10, but May as #1.

```
     Select (Month([ADate])+8) % 12 + 1
```